# Spring Configure Working Directory in Application Properties Relative vs. Absolute?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I want to configure a directory property that should be absolute or relative.

I know that within application.properties I can define properties. What I would like to know if I can define a relative component without post processing the property string.

So something 
directory=${root}/myDirectory

Since root is not known to configuration time but on runtime, I am a kind of puzzled.

Comment: Why don't you pass the location as VM parameter and start from there?

Comment: Not possible. Configuration Hustles. We have two properties, one for normal and one for testing. I guess you get the rest of the picture... .

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html